# Can not open .mp4 video with OpenCV 4.2 (videoCapture)

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to read a .mp4 video with OpenCV `VideoCapture` function, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
srcFile = '/opencv-text-detection/video/debat.mp4'
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(srcFile)
print (vs.isOpened())
```

`.isOpened` Returns always a `false`.

I am using Anconda 3, Python 3.8 and Opencv 4.2.0 with Python.

Comment: Try `cv.CaptureFromFile()` instead of  `VideoCapture`. And one more thing - are you sure first slash is compulsory?

Comment: are you sure that this is correct path?  `/` at the beginning means it is absolute path, not relative to your current folder.

Comment: I think it was related to Opencv version, when I tried with Opencv3 it worked, Thank you :)